# How would I make repeated sentence display only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

Observe that the same sentences are being repeated.  I'm trying to figure out a way to make them appear one time only.  I've tried using `Set()` as well as many other attempts but to no avail.

I've also tried to put them in an array but this attempt just puts each sentence into a separate array instead of comma separated.

Anyone know a good way to solve this so that each sentence isn't repeated (only displays once)?

```
{
     Object.keys(data).map((item,index) => {
        let arr = [];
        arr.push(data[item].favColor);
        console.log(arr);
     })
}
```

Result of `console.log(data[item].favColor);`

```
(3) My favorite color is Blue
(3) My favorite color is Blue
(12) My favorite color is Green
(12) My favorite color is Green
(5) My favorite color is Teal
(4) My favorite color is Red
(4) My favorite color is Red
(5) My favorite color is Teal
My favorite color is Purple
```

My React.js code:

```
{
    Object.keys(data).map((item,index) => {
         console.log(data[item].favColor);
         return <tr key={index}><td>{data[item].favColor}</td></tr>
    })
}
```

Comment: can you share the data?

Comment: Share how your tried to solve the problem with `Set`. And post the structure of `data`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli this is the structure of the data `(25) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: @GokulnathP structure of the data is posted in comment

Comment: @someone give us the object structure, it only shows '...'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let a = [
  '(3) My favorite color is Blue', 
  '(3) My favorite color is Blue', 
  '(12) My favorite color is Green', 
  '(4) My favorite color is Red', 
  '(4) My favorite color is Red'];

console.log(a.filter((el, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(el) === idx));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the good solution, but it will work for the structure you shared

```
let data = [
  {favColor: "some"}, 
  {favColor: "some"}, 
  {favColor: "some1"}, 
  {favColor: "some2"}, 
  {favColor: "some2"}
];

{
    data
     .map(item => JSON.stringify(item))
     .filter((item, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === index)
     .map(item => JSON.parse(item))
     .map((item,index) => {
         console.log(item.favColor);
         return <tr key={index}><td>{item.favColor}</td></tr>
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (*quick fix*)

```js
    {
        [...new Set(data.map(d=>d.favColor))].map((color,index) => {
             console.log(color);
             return <tr key={index}><td>{color}</td></tr>
        })
    }
```